# How to customize task scheduling in .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, task, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to achieve the following:

The main thread  should create some tasks (actually, there may be many threads, but let's simplify things for now to avoid extra complexity with concurrence and parallelism), which are somehow scheduled and executed later. Maybe by some `Timer` in fixed intervals, maybe later on the same thread when it blocks for these tasks, maybe by another thread designated specifically for this task - the implementation of scheduling isn't well-defined for now, I'm just trying to understand the basic idea.
I expect my code to look somehow like this:

```
'Somewhere in the main thread...
Dim MyTask = CreateTask(Of Integer)(Function()
    Console.WriteLine("Task has been called!")
    'Some activity...
    Return 42
End Sub)
'...
UseTheResult(MyTask.Result)
```

...where `CreateTask` is the subroutine responsive for scheduling delegates as tasks for later execution.

The thing is, I have no idea how to implement this concept. At first, I've tried to use the `SynchronizationContext`, but it seems to be more of the private thread memory and has nothing to do with scheduling tasks (although the Windows UI seems to use it somehow for this goal - I don't yet understand all this context thingie clearly). Then I've stumbled upon `TaskScheduler`, which, in conjuration with `TaskFactory`, seems to do just the thing. I've tried to make my implementation of this thread, but my code didn't work as expected, which implies I'm missing something very important about how `TaskScheduler` work, or even worse - about this whole concept at all. I've read a few articles on the subject (most notable, [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `TaskScheduler` and the code example with it), but still don't understand how does this work.

My not-working-as-expected-code, which was supposed to schedule and then execute tasks with delays of 100ms between them (so the whole test should have been running for ~10s):

```
Public Sub Main()
  Dim T As New TaskFactory(New TestScheduler)
  Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)
  For I = 1 To 100
    Dim J = I
    tasks.Add(T.StartNew(Sub() Console.WriteLine(J)))
  Next I
  Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray)

  Console.WriteLine("Test end")
  Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Class TestScheduler : Inherits TaskScheduler
  Dim Tasks As New Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue(Of Task)
  'Dim Counter As New Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)
  Dim CTimer As New Threading.Timer(AddressOf TimerUp, Nothing, 0, 100)
  Protected Overrides Function GetScheduledTasks() As IEnumerable(Of Task)
    Return Tasks
  End Function

  Private Sub TimerUp(State As Object)
    Static AllTasks% = 0
    Dim T As task = Nothing
    If Tasks.TryDequeue(T) Then
      Console.WriteLine("Task... {0}", AllTasks) 'for debugging
      AllTasks += 1
      If Not MyBase.TryExecuteTask(T) Then
        QueueTask(T)
      End If
    End If
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub QueueTask(task As Task)
    Tasks.Enqueue(task)
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Function TryExecuteTaskInline(task As Task, taskWasPreviouslyQueued As Boolean) As Boolean
    If taskWasPreviouslyQueued Then Return False
    Return MyBase.TryExecuteTask(task)
  End Function
End Class
'Output:
'2
'1
'2
'... and that's it, no even "Test end" or any other output whatsoever.
'I have strong feeling that it throws an exception somewhere; however,
'when I try to debug it, it silently stops, without waiting for <Enter>,
'and when I run it without debugging - it produces the abovementioned output without
'any exceptions or messages.
```

And I have very strong feeling I have misunderstood some basic concept here.

So, to summarize, my question is: **how do I customize task scheduling in .NET**?

What should I use - `SynchronizationContext`, `TaskScheduler`, derived classes or something else? If so, what are exact methods I should override and what is their meaning? All of these `QueueTask`, `TryExecuteTaskInline` and `TryExecuteTask` are simply bugging me crazy...

*P.S.: Please, forgive and, if you wish, correct any grammar or logical mistakes I made there. English is not my native and I'm not thinking very clearly at the moment [undersleeping]. Thank you!*

**EDIT:** I'm very sorry for misguiding you, everyone. The code was working *perfectly fine*, I've just made a very crude mistake by forgetting to mark my project as "Start-Up" - and so accidentally running another test project in the same solution... At first I was going to close the question, but then I realized it would be better to answer it instead - it should help anyone with the same problem, and, most importantly, allow for a far better solution: so far many questions are left unanswered. Why do we need `TaskScheduler.TryExecuteTask` - why "Try", exactly? When could this method return `False`?  When does the `TryExecuteTaskInline` method run, and when could it possibly execute with `taskWasPreviouslyQueued = true`? I have some assumptions, but, again, they may be wrong.

Do I need to raise these topics as separate questions, or, since they still fall under this question's title, they are fine to be there?

Comment: Have you looked into using `Semaphore` class, or `SemaphoreSlim`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. How should the `Semaphore` class help? As far as I know, it has nothing to do with task scheduling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in order to achieve this goal one may use the combination of `TaskScheduler` and `TaskFactory`, which worked perfectly for me:

```
Public Sub Main()
  Dim T As New TaskFactory(New TestScheduler)
  Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)
  For I = 1 To 100
    Dim J = I
    tasks.Add(T.StartNew(Sub() Console.WriteLine(J)))
  Next I
  Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray)

  Console.WriteLine("Test end")
  Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Public Function CreateTask(ActionToSchedule As Action) As Task
'This is exactly the needed function!
'A single static instances of both TaskFactory and custom TaskSheduler are used.
  Static Factory As New TaskFactory(New TestScheduler)
  Return Factory.StartNew(ActionToSchedule)
End Function

Class TestScheduler : Inherits TaskScheduler
  Dim Tasks As New Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue(Of Task)
  Dim CTimer As New Threading.Timer(AddressOf TimerUp, Nothing, 0, 10)
  Protected Overrides Function GetScheduledTasks() As IEnumerable(Of Task)
    Return Tasks
  End Function

  Private Sub TimerUp(State As Object)
    Static AllTasks% = 0
    Dim T As task = Nothing
    If Tasks.TryDequeue(T) Then
      Console.WriteLine("Task... {0}", AllTasks) 'for debugging purposes
      AllTasks += 1
      If Not MyBase.TryExecuteTask(T) Then
        QueueTask(T)
      End If
    End If
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub QueueTask(task As Task)
    'Here you should schedule the given task for later execution, whatever that means.
    'In this case it is simply put in the queue to be executed later when the timer fires.
    Tasks.Enqueue(task)
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Function TryExecuteTaskInline(task As Task, taskWasPreviouslyQueued As Boolean) As Boolean
    '> Attempts to execute the specified task on the current thread. 
    'As far as I understand - when the thread starts to wait for the task completion, either by trying to read
    '"task.Result" or executing "T.RunSynchronously()", this function will allow to execute the task synchronously
    'on the waiting thread instead of blocking, which may lead to a huge performance&speed gain.
    'If our task is not executing - waiting somewhere in the queue or is not even enqueued yet - we 
    'may dequeue it and run instantly to avoid the blocking.

    Return False
    'In this particular case, I've decided that the timer should run all the tasks, and, therefore, there must be done 
    'no inlining. Hovewer, the code below (obviously, it will not execute) should illustrate
    'this idea.
    If taskWasPreviouslyQueued Then
      'If the task is already enqueued, then we may try to remove it from
      'the queue and execute there instead.
      If Tasks.TryDequeue(task) Then
        Return MyBase.TryExecuteTask(task)
      Else
        'It has already been dequeued and maybe even completed already, so - no, no inlining. :)
        Return False
      End If
    Else
      'If it wasn't even enqueued - ha! No questions - we may run it now without any preparations.
      Return MyBase.TryExecuteTask(task)
    End If
  End Function
End Class
```

*I'm still not sure that a misguided question's correction and completion should be posted as the answer, but I hope it will do more good to community than simply closing it.*